# Sandboxed ironpython in c# SecurityException

Tags: c#, python, sandbox

Alright so this is what I have

```
private static AppDomain CreateSandbox()
{
  var permissions = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
  permissions.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));

  permissions.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read| FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
  var appinfo = new AppDomainSetup();
  appinfo.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

  return AppDomain.CreateDomain("Scripting sandbox", null, appinfo, permissions, fullTrustAssembly);
}
```

And when I try to load up some broken python code

```
try
{
    var src = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(s.Python, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
    src.Execute(ActionsScope);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ExceptionOperations eo = engine.GetService<ExceptionOperations>();
    string error = eo.FormatException(e);
    Debug.WriteLine(error);
}
```

This gives me a `SecurityException` instead of letting me see the actual exception from the code.
If I set the `PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted)` it works fine.

Any ideas on what permissions I need in order to catch these blasted errors?

```
System.Security.SecurityException was caught
  Message=Request failed.
  Source=Microsoft.Scripting
  GrantedSet=<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1">
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Read="F:\Programming\OCTGN\octgnFX\Octgn\bin\ReleaseMode with Debug\"
PathDiscovery="F:\Programming\OCTGN\octgnFX\Octgn\bin\ReleaseMode with Debug\"/>
<IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
version="1"
Flags="Execution"/>
</PermissionSet>

  PermissionState=<PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet"
version="1"
Unrestricted="true"/>

  RefusedSet=""
  Url=file:///F:/Programming/OCTGN/octgnFX/Octgn/bin/ReleaseMode with Debug/Microsoft.Scripting.DLL
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectCloneHelper.GetObjectData(Object serObj, String& typeName, String& assemName, String[]& fieldNames, Object[]& fieldValues)
       at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
       at Octgn.Scripting.Engine.LoadScripts() in F:\Programming\OCTGN\octgnFX\Octgn\Scripting\Engine.cs:line 58
  InnerException:
```

Comment: What SecurityException excatly? What are its parameters?

Comment: The code broken, what I'm trying to do is to catch the actual IronPython exception that it throws. This works when I give the sandbox full permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, you have a syntax error in your code, so the Python runtime throws `SyntaxErrorException`. That exception is not caught and so it has to be serialized across the appdomain boundary.

I think the problem now is that the method `GetObjectData()` of `SyntaxErrorException` is marked `[SecurityCritical]`, which means it can be called only by fully trusted code.

Comment: Just so you know, I obviously have a syntax error in my code. That's what I'm trying to catch.
What you are saying though is that with a `[SecurityCritical]` attribute, you have to have full permissions?

Comment: I think so. I'm not sure whether you can work around that somehow. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the ObjectHandle ExecuteAndWrap(ScriptScope scope, out ObjectHandle exception) overload.  When you're just catching the exception it gets marshaled from the remote domain to your domain when it's thrown, and then back to the remote domain when you call FormatException.  It looks like the exception is happening on the marshaling back to your app domain.

If you call the ExecuteAndWrap overload then you'll just get handles to the result and possible exception and avoid the serialization - you can then pass the handle back ExceptionOperations.FormatException.

Comment: Yeah can't seem to do that though as I can't specify the way I want the script to load.

Comment: Do you have an example of the syntax on how to do this? I have been looking all over the place for this, but can't seem to find a good reference.